# ¿Qué significa <T extends Comparable>...?

Tags: java, genéricos

```
public static <T extends Comparable> T getMenor(T[] a) {

    if (a.length <= 1 || a == null) {
        return null;
    }

    T menorElemento = a[0];

    for (int i=1; i<a.length; i++) {

        if (menorElemento.compareTo(a[i]) > 0 ) {//Si menorEle es mayor a a[i], entonces el menor es a[i]
            menorElemento = a[i];
        }

    }

    return menorElemento;
}
```

Entiendo que el método recibe un parámetro de tipo `T` (genérico). Lo que no entiendo es esta parte:

```
T extends Comparable
```

¿Qué significa? ¿Alguien podría explicármelo?

Comment: En lugar de `a.length <= 1 || a == null` debe ser `a == null || a.length <= 1 `. De no ser así, obtendrías `NullPointerException`.

Comment: A quienes votan por cerrar por no entender lo que se pregunta: existen 3 respuestas y un comentario sobre el tema. y al menos 3 usuarios tienen más de 1k de reputación, es decir, tienen experiencia en el sitio y saben que la pregunta es válida, por ende aportan en la solución.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`<T extends Comparable>` significa que el método **en tiempo de compilación** define un tipo de variable genérico pero la clase o interfaz debe implementar o extender de la interfaz `Comparable`. De esta manera, se restringe el uso de los clientes de este método.

---

Cabe resaltar que el método tiene un problema: indica que la clase/interfaz genérica debe implementar/extender de `Comparable` pero no restringe a que la clase sea `Comparable` de sí misma. Es decir, este código sería válido:

```
public class Bar { }
public class Foo implements Comparable<Bar> {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Bar b) {
        //implementación descabellada, no utilizar
        //en código de producción
        return 0;
    }
}

//...

Foo[] arrayFoo = ...;
Foo menor = getMenor(arrayFoo); //compila y corre sin problemas
```

Para corregir este error, el genérico debería estar declarado de esta manera:

```
<T extends Comparable<? super T>>
```

Comment: por que no solo: `<T extends Comparable<T>>` ?

Comment: @OscarRyz lo hice por la definición utilizada comúnmente en `Comparator`, como puedes encontrar en `Arrays#sort`, `Collections#sort`, en las fuentes de `TreeMap` y otros ejemplos en las fuentes de JDK.

Comment: Entonces sería `public static <T> T getMenor(Comparable<? super T>[] a)` que es distinto.

Comment: @OscarRyz en el caso que colocas, estás diciendo que el método solo podrá recibir como parámetro arreglos de tipo `Comparable[]`, recuerda el type erasure o "borrado de tipos" (¿traducción correcta?). Mi estrategia indica que el arreglo sea de cualquier tipo genérico T donde T extienda o implemente la interfaz `Comparable` y que T sea comparable de sí mismo o de un tipo superior a él.

Comment: @user227 ¿Por qué se usa  "extends" y no "implements" ya que "Comparable" es una interfaz?

Answer (score 6):

Así por encima [`Comparable <T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) es un `generic interface`

```
public static <T extends Comparable> T ...
```

ahora con  T, viene a ser algo como indicando:

> *vale tu pasame lo que quieras pero que implemente la interface `Comparable`.*

---

El método `compareTo()` que es usado dentro de ese método (en tu ejemplo), pertenece a la interface `Comparable` es una de las cosas del por qué `extends Comprable`, por lo que en su código tiene algo así:

```
T menorElemento = a[0];
..//
menorElemento.compareTo()
.//
```

de lo que deducimos que el/los objeto/s `T` que usen tienen que tener dicho método, y como lo consigues implementándolo, en este caso la con Interface Comparable, y para indicarle, que los tipos genéricos tiene que implementar dicha interface lo hacemos en la definición del método por ejemplo:

`public static <T>` indica que maneja tipos genéricos, pero así `public static <T extends Comparable>` le decimos que los tipos genéricos tienen que implementar la intefaz `Comparable`.

Esos objetos tienen que implementarla, así que todos los parámetros, por ejemplo que le pasemos `getMenor(T[] a)` tienen que tenerla implementada, de ahí el uso de `extends` porque si le pasamos otro tipo que no implementa esa interface, te dará un error al hacer por ejemplo esto `menorElemento.compareTo()` y claro ese `T` igual no tiene ese método, espero me entiendas.

Puedes mirar un ejemplo de la [Clase String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

```
public final class String
extends Object
implements Serializable, Comparable<String>, CharSequence
```

básicamente es algo como, los `T` que quieras usar, (y los que te retornare) tienen que tener implementada la interface que indicas aquí `<T extends Comparable>`.

Comment: Claro entendí todo, pero me quedo una duda. Porque es se usa extends y no implements? Ya que se trata de una interfaz.

Comment: @MatiEzelQ así se definió esa parte del lenguaje, es más allí puedes extender de múltiples interfaces: `<T extends Comparable<? super T> & Serializable>`.

Comment: @MatiEzelQ puedes encontrar la definición formal en la especificación del lenguaje Java: [4.5 Parameterized Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5) (en inglés)

Answer (score 1):

Lo que quiere decir `T` en este contexto, es que acepta *cualquier* tipo de objeto que sea o que herede de [**`java.lang.Comparable`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) (interfaz). En tu caso,  almacena en `menorElemento` la primera posición del arreglo recibido de tipo `<T extends Comparable>` para después realizar una comprobación de quién es el menor del arreglo.

---

Para saber más:

- Interfaz `java.lang.Comparable<T>`: [*ENLACE*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)
- Explicación Genéricos: [*ENLACE*](http://www.arquitecturajava.com/uso-de-java-generics/)