# Hola compañeros estoy haciendo esta interface y no se como poner el método default compareTo que comparará el área de dos objetos alguna idea? gracias

Tags: java

```
public interface InterfazFigura{

    //METODOS ABSTRACTOS:
    double area();//"public abstract" (es opcional, no hace falta ponerlo, es x defecto)
    //METODOS POR DEFECTOS
    default public String etiquetaArea() {
        return "Area Rectángulo";// codificación por defecto
    }
                //AQUÍ TENDRÍA EL MÉTODO compareTo()

    //METODOS ESTÁTICOS
    static public String longitudeEnBinario(double lonxitude) {
        return Double.toHexString(lonxitude);
    }   
    }
```

---

```
default public <T> int compareTo (T outro) {
    return this.compareTo(outro);
}// esto estaria bien?
```

Comment: No me queda claro lo que quieres hacer. No describas tu pregunta en el título. Para tener la función compareTo debes implementar la interfaz Comparable en tu clase. Quizás sea mejor idea que el código que estás presentando sea una clase abstracta ya que una interfaz no puede implementar otra interfaz. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Qué significa <T extends Comparable>...?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/4672/qu%c3%a9-significa-t-extends-comparable)

Comment: Muchas gracias Mateo, puse el método compareTo como abstracto en la interface, después la implementé en la clase. Gracias por tu ayuda